# I can't get the url with Pattern.compile

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

What I really want is to return the URLs that are in the txt variable. the url comes from randomly then not are regular expreccion to use or not is part of my code this poorly written... use google translator only sorry I speak Spanish; ol

```
//I can't get the url with Pattern.compile

//My code example::::: in the works :(

String txt="sources: [{file:\"http://pla.cdn19.fx.rrrrrr.com/luq5t4nidtixexzw6wblbiexs7hg2hdu4coqdlltx6t3hu3knqhbfoxp7jna/normal.mp4\",label:\"360p\"}],sources: [{file:\"http://pla.cdn19.fx.rrrrrr.com/luq5t4nidtixexzw6wblbiexs7hg2hdu4coqdlltx6t3hu3knqhbfoxp7jna/normal.mp4\",label:\"360p\"}]";

ArrayList<String> getfi = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("sources: [{file:\"(.*)\"").matcher(txt);

if (matcher.find()) {
    while(matcher.find()) {
        getfi.add(matcher.group(1));
    }  
    System.out.println(getfi);

} else {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: That looks like a JSON string. Strongly suggest using a JSON parser.

Comment: as I do that   not is how to do it

Comment: No clue what that was supposed to mean. Are you saying you *don't* want to use a JSON parser to parse JSON text, so any encoding issues are handled for you, automatically?

Comment: If I want to use it if but not is how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Pattern.compile("sources: [{file:\"(.*)\"")
> ```

You regex is wrong, since both `[` and `{` are special characters, so they must be escaped. Which is why you get `PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 21`, which you didn't mention in your question.

Also the pattern will match the entire string, except for the last two characters.

> ```
> if (matcher.find()) {
>     while(matcher.find()) {
> ```

The `find()` call in the `if` statement consumes the first find. Since the first find is the entire text except last two characters, there is no second find for the `find()` call in the `while` loop, so loop is never entered.

To make it work, escape the special characters, change `.*` to not be greedy, and fix the loop:

```
String txt="sources: [{file:\"http://pla.cdn19.fx.rrrrrr.com/luq5t4nidtixexzw6wblbiexs7hg2hdu4coqdlltx6t3hu3knqhbfoxp7jna/normal.mp4\",label:\"360p\"}],sources: [{file:\"http://pla.cdn19.fx.rrrrrr.com/luq5t4nidtixexzw6wblbiexs7hg2hdu4coqdlltx6t3hu3knqhbfoxp7jna/normal.mp4\",label:\"360p\"}]";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("sources: \\[\\{file:\"(.*?)\"").matcher(txt);

ArrayList<String> getfi = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    getfi.add(matcher.group(1));
}
if (getfi.isEmpty()) {
    System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println(getfi);
```

**WARNING:**
 Notice that sometimes there is a space after `:`, and sometimes not. That is perfectly valid for JSON. JSON text may contain whitespace, including newlines, so using a simple regex is not a good idea.

Use a JSON parser instead.

Comment: Thank you very much ♥ I had an entire day breaking my head... thanks (solved)